# ERROR code 1452 mysql occurs in windows but not in linux

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I have a django project that creates tables after manage.py migrate.
I use some LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE MySQL queries for both.
I have 7 tables.
All the first 6 tables are populated the same way in both Linux and Windows.
Except for the last table that has some foreign keys in previous ones.

[image: Linux MySQL Output]

[image: Windows MySQL Output]

Both Windows and Linux tables are in InnoDB and the parent table has exactly the same data.

```
INSERT INTO `seas_database`.`section_t`
(`eSession`,`eDays`,`dYear`,`nSectionNumber`,`nSectionCapacity`,`nEnrolled`,`bIsBlocked`,`tStartTime`,`tEndTime`,`cCoffCode_ID`,`cFaculty_ID`,`cRoom_ID`)
VALUES
("Spring","F",2009,1,250,43,0,"14:00","15:30","AAT101","T001","C10210-S");
```

[Proof that AAT101 exists in Windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5O8d.png)

Yet i get this error in Windows ONLY. Not in Linux.

```
Error Code: 1452. 
Cannot add or update a child row: 
a foreign key constraint fails 
(`seas_database`.`section_t`, CONSTRAINT `section_t_cCoffCode_ID_ade53504_fk_cooffered` FOREIGN KEY (`cCoffCode_ID`) 
REFERENCES `coofferedcourse_t` (`cCoffCode_ID`))
```

Linux MySQL version :

```
mysql  Ver 8.0.27 for Linux on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)
```

Windows MySQL version:

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysql.exe  Ver 8.0.27 for Win64 on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)
```

If it helps, the csv for which the LOAD DATA INFILE was ran, it was modified and created by  Pandas from an xlsx file.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please give the command `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename` for each relevant table, in both the Windows and Linux environments.  Then please [edit] your question to show us that output. You can indent text four spaces to format that sort of data as source code.

Comment: Please copy paste output instead of putting images https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: This issue has nothing to do with the operating system, or pandas, or django. As you wrote in the question, a table in the windows-based mysql has foreign keys. The FK checks fail, hence the error message.

Comment: In windows the backslash in the path must be either quoted (doubled) or replaced with slash. I.e. either `C:\\Program Files\\MySQL...` or `'C:/Program Files/MySQL....'`. Last variant is preferred.

Comment: @Akina The Local infile commands had / slashes in them for both windows and linux.
So that cannot be an issue.
As proof, the previous table populations worked.

Comment: Your screenshot contradicts your words.

Comment: @Akina Oh i see what you mean, the mysql command line client just ran a sql file. Not the actual command. This is one of the queries in that sql file:-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
-- Populating CoOfferedCourse_T
LOAD DATA LOCAL
INFILE "C:/Users/Mir Shafayat Ahmed/Student-Enrollment-Analysis-System/courseCodeData.csv" 
INTO TABLE CoOfferedCourse_T 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY "\t"
IGNORE 1 LINES 
(@COFFER_COURSE_ID,@COFFERED_WITH)
SET cCoffCode_ID=@COFFERED_WITH,cCourse_ID=@COFFER_COURSE_ID;
```

Comment: `Error number: 1452; Symbol: ER_NO_REFERENCED_ROW_2; SQLSTATE: 23000 Message: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (%s)` This error is **not** related to the file path. It tells that the SQL commands in .SQL file or the data loaded from .CSV file causes FK constraint violation error.

Comment: @Akina Yes this error is not related to filepath. You mentioned it previously, hence i replied

Comment: @O.Jones Edited :)

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

The solution turned out to be indeed platform specific.
The line terminating character in the auto generated csv file i was loading data from, varied in Windows and Linux.
So, while in linux i never faced an issue with the code below,

```
-- Populating CoOfferedCourse_T
LOAD DATA LOCAL
INFILE "path/to/foo.csv" 
INTO TABLE coofferedcourse_t 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY "\t"
IGNORE 1 LINES 
(@COFFER_COURSE_ID,@COFFERED_WITH)
SET cCoffCode_ID=@COFFERED_WITH,cCourse_ID=@COFFER_COURSE_ID;
```

In windows, i had to add

```
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
```

After which the table states in both platforms became identical